# cannot set onsuccess callback for indexeddb add transaction

Tags: indexeddb

i get a problem to set the callback function before indexeddb add transaction

```
os = ...the object store (IDBObjectStore) object assigned here
os.onsuccess = function(){alert('dont mess with Messi')}
os.add({name:'Lionel Messi',team:'FC Barcelona',position:'striker',number:10});
```

the entry was successfully added to the object store, but the function on onsuccess event won't fired. there's another event called onerror. should i use it instead? i dont think so

don't ask me for 'can you give the error part?' because there's no error at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going about your request in the wrong way. There's no error because you're merely adding an `onsuccess` attribute to an object that will never call it.

You don't add `onsuccess` callbacks to the object store, you open a transaction on the `objectStore` and add a listener to that transaction.

For a working example using indexes and transactions, check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorbuley/TLTfn/) I was recently working through with another StackOverflower.* For a more complex example, see [my IndexedDB library](https://github.com/editor/InDB/blob/master/indb.dev.js).

*Note this fiddle is written to the old (pre-Dec 2011), Chrome IDB implementation. A newer (FF) implementation would use an `onupgradeneeded` callback but would more or less otherwise be the same.

Comment: i cant do it since my rep is still below 15

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your assigning handler to wrong object, onsuccess, onerror, onabort handlers are fired by transaction, not object store itself, so the code would look like:

```
transaction = database.transaction([storeName], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
 ..
 ..
os = transaction.objectStore(storeName);
transaction.oncomplete = function(e) { //do your stuff here } ;
os.add({ id : 1, name : 'John Doe'});
```

Can you post a code, how are you getting object store, I guess from transaction (don't know of other ways to do it).Please let me know if code above works. Note that object that you're inserting must have property defined as objectStore's key when creating object store.

Comment: os = db.transaction(os_name,'readwrite').objectStore(os_name);

something weird here. why not we have to use transaction to add the entry. but the callback still fired by transaction object. whatever

anyway thanx buddy